# Monoid object in a category.

Tags: category-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)

In this definition of Monoid object, what exactly is the $I$ in $\eta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, $I$ is part of the data for the monoidal category to which the monoid object belongs. It is the unit object (or identity object) of the monoidal category $C$. See the Wikipedia page on [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) for more details.